# Variant of "Exact Cover by 3-Set "

Tags: np-complete, np, set-cover

Exact cover by 3-sets is -complete:

Instance: Given a finite set $X = \{x_1, x_2, …, x_{3n}\}$ of $3n$ elements and a collection $C = \{(x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, x_{i_3})\}$ of 3-elements subsets of $X$;

Question: Find a subcollection $C'$ of $C$ such that every element in $X$ is contained in exactly one member of $C'$.

**Now if we impose a restriction on the cardinality (size) of $C$, that is, we require $||=(3n/2)-1$, then is the restricted exact cover by 3 set problem still NP-hard?**

Comment: For $|C| = 3n$, the problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard: [link](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20386/restriction-of-exact-cover-by-3-sets)

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, |C|=3n, it is still NP-hard. But how about |C|=(3n/2)-1 ?, is it still NP-hard?